# How do I make 2d collisions based on color?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics

I'm a Unity noob; digital artist, first and foremost. I just want to know how I can make a simple collider for my 2d car, based on the 2 colors of this 2d map. I want it so the car doesn't touch the white, but can run smoothly on the black road. Thank you, in advance.

[image: 2d black and white city map]

Comment: To do this with the built-in 2D physics system, you'll need to create Colliders representing the area you want to be solid. You can do this manually, by creating GameObjects with BoxCollider2D components attached, sized & overlapped to cover your shapes. Or you could convert the black to transparency and see whether Unity's PolygonCollider2D will do a decent job of tracing the contours automatically. You could also roll your own non-physics-based movement, sampling points from the texture to decide whether the car can proceed. Which approach makes more sense for your project?